# checked and disabled checkbox based on mysql condition in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I have a page with users listing in admin section. I have the approved users with disabled checkboxes and unapproved users with enabled checkboxes. Now I want to show approved users as "checked" and disable checkboxes. I searched a lot but couldn't get clue. PLease a help or suggestyion will be appreciated.

Here is my code for that,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="all_check[]" <?php echo $disabled ;?> value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="checkbox" id="status" ></td>
```

And the condition to show disabled as,

```
if ($status == '1') { 

    $disabled = "disabled";
}
```

Comment: `$disabled = "disabled checked";`

Comment: if($status == '1'){
        $disabled = "disabled = 'disabled' checked='checked' ";
}

Comment: Well it worked.. Thanks a lot. @Suren

Comment: But I have the table header as "Check for approval" and there is a checkbox too.. so how to remove  that checkbox for approved candidates. I know its another question but results are not up to the mark :( Here is that table header : <th> Check for Approval <input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/> </th> I want to remove the checkbox for Approved candidates.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="all_check[]" <?php if($row['id']==1) echo 'disabled checked="checked"';?> value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="checkbox" id="status" ></td>
```

Where your disabled and checked condition should be based on the value stored in your database table column. Above you can change the $row['id'] to what you have used to store the approved column.